# soap api : Start tag expected, '&lt;' not found'

Tags: api, soap, magento-1.7

I am getting some soap fault error with the message as below :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><SOAP-ENV:Body><SOAP-ENV:Fault><faultcode>WSDL</faultcode><faultstring>SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from 'http://magento/index.php/api/index/index/?wsdl=1' : Start tag expected, '&lt;' not found
</faultstring></SOAP-ENV:Fault></SOAP-ENV:Body></SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

FYI : It was working few days before. We created one of the store recently and we also removed each and every file regarding new store including etc/modules, newly installed extensions and layout files.

When we try to access url from SSH using wget command

```
shop@magento:~/htdocs$ wget www.magento.com/api/index
--2014-04-04 08:59:37--  http://www.magento.com/api/index
Resolving www.magento.com... 12.345.678.901
Connecting to www.magento.com|12.345.678.901|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 500 Internal Service Error
2014-04-04 08:59:48 ERROR 500: Internal Service Error.
```

If I try to access http://www.magento.com/api.php?type=soap&wsdl=1

I am getting following output.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<definitions xmlns:typens="urn:Magento" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"
    xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"
    name="Magento" targetNamespace="urn:Magento">
    <types>
        <schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="urn:Magento">
<!--            <import namespace="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" schemaLocation="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" />-->
            <complexType name="FixedArray">
                <complexContent>
                    <restriction base="soapenc:Array">
                        <attribute ref="soapenc:arrayType" wsdl:arrayType="xsd:anyType[]" />
                    </restriction>
                </complexContent>
            </complexType>
        </schema>
    </types>
    <message name="call">
        <part name="sessionId" type="xsd:string" />
        <part name="resourcePath" type="xsd:string" />
        <part name="args" type="xsd:anyType" />
    </message>
    <message name="callResponse">
        <part name="callReturn" type="xsd:anyType" />
    </message>
    <message name="multiCall">
        <part name="sessionId" type="xsd:string" />
        <part name="calls" type="typens:FixedArray" />
        <part name="options" type="xsd:anyType" />
    </message>
    <message name="multiCallResponse">
        <part name="multiCallReturn" type="typens:FixedArray" />
    </message>
    <message name="endSession">
        <part name="sessionId" type="xsd:string" />
    </message>
    <message name="endSessionResponse">
        <part name="endSessionReturn" type="xsd:boolean" />
    </message>
    <message name="login">
        <part name="username" type="xsd:string" />
        <part name="apiKey" type="xsd:string" />
    </message>
    <message name="loginResponse">
        <part name="loginReturn" type="xsd:string" />
    </message>
    <message name="resources">
        <part name="sessionId" type="xsd:string" />
    </message>
    <message name="resourcesResponse">
        <part name="resourcesReturn" type="typens:FixedArray" />
    </message>
    <message name="globalFaults">
        <part name="sessionId" type="xsd:string" />
    </message>
    <message name="globalFaultsResponse">
        <part name="globalFaultsReturn" type="typens:FixedArray" />
    </message>
    <message name="resourceFaults">
        <part name="resourceName" type="xsd:string" />
        <part name="sessionId" type="xsd:string" />
    </message>
    <message name="resourceFaultsResponse">
        <part name="resourceFaultsReturn" type="typens:FixedArray" />
    </message>
    <message name="startSession" />
    <message name="startSessionResponse">
        <part name="startSessionReturn" type="xsd:string" />
    </message>
    <portType name="Mage_Api_Model_Server_HandlerPortType">
        <operation name="call">
            <documentation>Call api functionality</documentation>
            <input message="typens:call" />
            <output message="typens:callResponse" />
        </operation>
        <operation name="multiCall">
            <documentation>Multiple calls of resource functionality</documentation>
            <input message="typens:multiCall" />
            <output message="typens:multiCallResponse" />
        </operation>
        <operation name="endSession">
            <documentation>End web service session</documentation>
            <input message="typens:endSession" />
            <output message="typens:endSessionResponse" />
        </operation>
        <operation name="login">
            <documentation>Login user and retrive session id</documentation>
            <input message="typens:login" />
            <output message="typens:loginResponse" />
        </operation>
        <operation name="startSession">
            <documentation>Start web service session</documentation>
            <input message="typens:startSession" />
            <output message="typens:startSessionResponse" />
        </operation>
        <operation name="resources">
            <documentation>List of available resources</documentation>
            <input message="typens:resources" />
            <output message="typens:resourcesResponse" />
        </operation>
        <operation name="globalFaults">
            <documentation>List of resource faults</documentation>
            <input message="typens:globalFaults" />
            <output message="typens:globalFaultsResponse" />
        </operation>
        <operation name="resourceFaults">
            <documentation>List of global faults</documentation>
            <input message="typens:resourceFaults" />
            <output message="typens:resourceFaultsResponse" />
        </operation>
    </portType>
    <binding name="Mage_Api_Model_Server_HandlerBinding" type="typens:Mage_Api_Model_Server_HandlerPortType">
        <soap:binding style="rpc" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" />
        <operation name="call">
            <soap:operation soapAction="urn:Mage_Api_Model_Server_HandlerAction" />
            <input>
                <soap:body namespace="urn:Magento" use="encoded" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" />
            </input>
            <output>
                <soap:body namespace="urn:Magento" use="encoded" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" />
            </output>
        </operation>
        <operation name="multiCall">
            <soap:operation soapAction="urn:Mage_Api_Model_Server_HandlerAction" />
            <input>
                <soap:body namespace="urn:Magento" use="encoded" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" />
            </input>
            <output>
                <soap:body namespace="urn:Magento" use="encoded" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" />
            </output>
        </operation>
        <operation name="endSession">
            <soap:operation soapAction="urn:Mage_Api_Model_Server_HandlerAction" />
            <input>
                <soap:body namespace="urn:Magento" use="encoded" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" />
            </input>
            <output>
                <soap:body namespace="urn:Magento" use="encoded" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" />
            </output>
        </operation>
        <operation name="login">
            <soap:operation soapAction="urn:Mage_Api_Model_Server_HandlerAction" />
            <input>
                <soap:body namespace="urn:Magento" use="encoded" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" />
            </input>
            <output>
                <soap:body namespace="urn:Magento" use="encoded" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" />
            </output>
        </operation>
        <operation name="startSession">
            <soap:operation soapAction="urn:Mage_Api_Model_Server_HandlerAction" />
            <input>
                <soap:body namespace="urn:Magento" use="encoded" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" />
            </input>
            <output>
                <soap:body namespace="urn:Magento" use="encoded" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" />
            </output>
        </operation>
        <operation name="resources">
            <soap:operation soapAction="urn:Mage_Api_Model_Server_HandlerAction" />
            <input>
                <soap:body namespace="urn:Magento" use="encoded" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" />
            </input>
            <output>
                <soap:body namespace="urn:Magento" use="encoded" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" />
            </output>
        </operation>
        <operation name="globalFaults">
            <soap:operation soapAction="urn:Mage_Api_Model_Server_HandlerAction" />
            <input>
                <soap:body namespace="urn:Magento" use="encoded" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" />
            </input>
            <output>
                <soap:body namespace="urn:Magento" use="encoded" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" />
            </output>
        </operation>
        <operation name="resourceFaults">
            <soap:operation soapAction="urn:Mage_Api_Model_Server_HandlerAction" />
            <input>
                <soap:body namespace="urn:Magento" use="encoded" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" />
            </input>
            <output>
                <soap:body namespace="urn:Magento" use="encoded" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" />
            </output>
        </operation>
    </binding>
    <service name="MagentoService">
        <port name="Mage_Api_Model_Server_HandlerPort" binding="typens:Mage_Api_Model_Server_HandlerBinding">
            <soap:address location="http://www.magento.com/index.php/?type=soap" />
        </port>
    </service>
</definitions>
```

My current magento version is 1.7.0.2, required PHP extensions are loaded. Please help me, I am getting stuck since last two days.

Edit :
One of the important thing, when we remove theme switcher code base on server host, we are getting following soap fault code by running http://www.magento.com/api/index :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><SOAP-ENV:Body><SOAP-ENV:Fault><faultcode>Sender</faultcode><faultstring>Invalid XML</faultstring></SOAP-ENV:Fault></SOAP-ENV:Body></SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Here is the switcher code we placed into root index

```
switch($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']) {
    case 'test1.magento1.com':
        define('STORECODE1', 'storecode1_storeview');           
        Mage::run(STORECODE1,$mageRunType);
    break;
    case 'www.magento.com':
        define('MOBILESTORECODE', 'mobilemagento');
        if (isMobile()) {
            $mobile = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParam('mobile');
            if(isset($mobile) && $mobile == 'no') {         
                Mage::run($mageRunCode, $mageRunType);
            }else{                  
                Mage::run($mageRunCode, $mageRunType);
                //Mage::run(MOBILESTORECODE,$mageRunType);
            }
        } else {                        
            Mage::run($mageRunCode, $mageRunType);
        }
    break;
    default:
        Mage::run($mageRunCode, $mageRunType);
    break;
}
```

Also, using this url with the store switcher code removed, we are getting - http://www.magento.com/api.php?type=soap

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><SOAP-ENV:Body><SOAP-ENV:Fault><faultcode>WSDL</faultcode><faultstring>SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from 'http://www.magento.com/index.php/?type=soap&amp;wsdl=1' : Extra content at the end of the document
```

Comment: What did you do with the`default`block of that switch statement?

Comment: It has to do nothing..

Comment: Somewhere in index.php there should be a call to Mage::run(). Fix that first, then see how far you get.

Comment: I did not find any code calling run method from index.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found out the solution after 3 days juggling. Thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12538343/magento-api-soap-error-parsing-wsdl-couldnt-load-from-url-index-php-api-in I had not noticed yet the correct response(Literally my mistake).

I was getting following warning from index that I ignored

```
PHP Notice:  Undefined index: HTTP_USER_AGENT in index.php on line xx
PHP Notice:  Undefined index: HTTP_SERVER in index.php on line xx.
```

I turned off

```
ini_set('display_errors', 0);
```

and now, API's got working and looking to solve warnings.. So, issue - system is expecting start tag of xml reponse as '<' while it was being given xml with warning message, though warnings were not being displayed in xml response.

Comment: HTTP_USER_AGENT isn't always available. HTTP_SERVER, is probably a typo for $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']. Too many people are told to develop with `display_errors` on. It's just as easy to develop with a properly configured `error_log`, a console, `tail -f /path/to/that/error_log` and enough screen space.