# SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from : failed to load external entity

Tags: soap, magento-community

Hi we are getting the following error

**SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from 'https://www.hourglassangel.com/api/v2_soap?wsdl=1' : failed to load external entity "https://www.hourglassangel.com/api/v2_soap?wsdl=1"**

what could possibly be the reason for this SOAP error. Can anyone help us out with a solution ASAP.

**Curlwrappers are already disabled.**

**ATTENTION:**

**As suggested, i checked out this post [soap api : Start tag expected, '&lt;' not found'](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/17892/soap-api-start-tag-expected-lt-not-found)
I found that ini_set('display_errors',0); is already turned off. Still unable to overcome the SOAP error.**

Comment: How about http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/30068/bug-in-ce-version-1-9-0-1-connecting-via-soap-v1

Comment: @David But my site's community edition version is **Magento ver. 1.5.1.0**. Is there a bug in this version also?